# How does the spam filters of big email providers cooperate with mail clients?

Tags: email

In web interface is enough to press "spam" button and the message is transfered to spam folder. In email client i don't use such button, but simple move message to spam folder.

Do they learn from these moved messages?

**Edit:** If i move message from spam folder to normal folder, do they recognize this action?

Answer (score 0):

No. A corporate spamfilter will not learn from any action taken on the client side. It is possible to go to the configuration of the spamfilter and make adjustments to the rule, but a corporate spamfilter checks spam differently.

There are several methods used which is way too broad to be talking about here.

Generally you should know that most spamfilters use lists with known bad spammers to block email and also block based on the email content and the domain's SPF record.

Some spamfilters will quarantine the email in their spamfilter and the email is never delivered. A daily report is sent and one can then enter the spamfilter to make it pass trough. Usually these spamfilters use whitelists to allow email adresses or domains to get past.

Other spamfilters will mark the email as being spam but still deliver it, so clients such as Outlook will move the email to the junk folder. Whitelisting in outlook is the same. You specify one email address or the entire domain, and even if it is classified as spam, it will not be seen as spam anymore.

The only difference in setting the whitelist in the spamfilter rather than the client, is that the spamfilter can be used company wide, where a client is always one client.